# Conditional element in xaml depending on the binding content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to display this TextBlock, only if the `Address.Length > 0` ? I'd like to do this directly into the xaml, I know I could put all my controls programmatically

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Address}" />
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basically, you're going to need to write an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) so that you can bind the `Visibility` property of your `TextBox` to either the `Address` field, or a new field that you create.

If you bind to the `Address` field, here's how the binding might look like::

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Address}"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Address, Converter={StaticResource StringLengthVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

And then `StringLengthVisiblityConverter` could look something like this:

```
public class StringLengthVisiblityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Don't need to implement this
    }
}
```

Then you'd just need to add your converter as a resource, using syntax like this (where `src` is mapped to the namespace where the converter is defined):

```
<src:StringLengthVisiblityConverter x:Key="StringLengthVisiblityConverter" />
```

Comment: The XAML is missing a curly bracket, if I spotted that correctly, no?

Comment: @Tobias I think you're right, although in full disclosure I haven't done anything with XAML in years so I'm a bit rusty. I've updated the answer, however - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

I would do this with another boolean property called `HasAddress` which returns `Address.Length > 0`.

```
<!-- In some resources section -->
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Bool2VisibilityConverter" />

<TextBlock 
  Text="{Binding Address}" 
  Visibility="{Binding HasAddress, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisibilityConverter}}" 
/>
```

You should also remember to notify the property change for `HasAddress` in the setter of `Address`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `StringToVisibility` converter.

It will return `Visibility.Visible` if bound string `is not null or empty` and `Visibility.Collapsed` if it is.

Use this converter while binding `Address` with `Visibility` property of your `TextBlock`.

### Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Address}" Visibility="{Binding Address, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```